# Localization not working - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization, localizable.strings

I have a problem with the localization of my app. I want to have french and english (default).

The localization seems to work with the Storyboard as text from there is translated to french (on simulator & iPhone in french). But the strings from Localizable.strings are not translated.

I checked the name of the file and it is correct "Localizable.strings". I validated the content of the files with "plutil -lint " and it was OK.
Checking the target->build phases->copy bundle resources: the Localizable.strings is there.

In the code I am using:

```
NSLocalizedString("KEY", comment: "")
```

Checking the NSLocale of the simulator, it seems as the preferred language is french, so I do not understand why it is not working.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Henry

Comment: This is not a help in any way - just want to say thanks for mentioning that the file must be named: "Localizable.strings" .. I had (for unknown reasons) named it something else - and just couldn't understand why it didn't work - until now. Thanks :-P

Comment: For change language "on the fly" you can use http://cocoapods.org/pods/L10n-swift.

Comment: In my case I have replaced the file name with default name `Localizable.strings`. Now it is working fine.In my project so many pods with language changes, so it is not reloading immediately, after second time reopening the app then it's working. So I have replaced with default file name `Localizable.strings`.

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing some settings in your scheme.

This [tutorial](http://youtu.be/YpNU6HbkMjQ) on YouTube really helped me localize my last app. It's under 8 minutes. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is a scheme issue. As it is not working, on the iPhone and on the simulator (only storyboard but not strings from code). Moreover, I did what was mentioned in the tutorial ;)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue. There was a mistake in my Localizable.strings. I had the following for one line:

```
"..."; = "...";
```

It would be good if there was a tool to validate this.

Thanks for the effort,

Bye

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue, but I found a mistake in Localizable.strings as user3900157.
I missed semicolon at the end. After added semicolon to all sentences, it worked.
Hope to help you.

Comment: For me it was an __extra__ semicolon: ";;" which builds without warnings, for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I have got same issue in **Xcode 12.5**

**My Issues:** I **worked with English and Arabic text**. English text was working fine **but not able to extract Arabic Text**. Have tried all solutions.

**My Solution 1:**
Actually I had *copied and pasted Arabic text from Google which caused issue in Xcode(Xcode was not able to read those texts*.)
So *I copied Arabic texts first in Notes App and then copied to Xcode*.

**My Solution 2:**
I have tracked this issue after 4-5 afters.
I checked the texts which are working fine in Arabic and checked the last line from where texts are not working. So i found that Arabic text was pasted improperly. So I cut that text and copied to Notes App and copied from Notes App and pasted back to code.

And Boom It worked.