# NSLocalizedString not getting value for the key

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

I have a 2 localized string files, one for Romanian and one for English. In both files I have this line:

English:

```
"invalidSum" = "Invalid amount"
```

Romanian:

```
"invalidSum" = "Suma invalida"
```

I use this message in a alert like this:

```
  let titleAlert = NSLocalizedString("invalidSum", comment: "")

    let sumAlert = UIAlertController(title: titleAlert, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    sumAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
    present(sumAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

However, whenever the alert shows, I get the message "invalidSum", not "Invalid amount" for english localization and "Suma invalida" for romanian localization. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There should be a semi-colon at the end of each key/value pair in the strings file.

Comment: Are you sure that you have setup the Localizable.strings right? are they specified for the desired target(s)? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35732333/localization-not-working-swift

Comment: @MartinR I assume that missing a semi-colon should leads to the "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format" compile-time error, at least that's what happening in my case...

Comment: I added the semi-colon and it's still not working. The strings files were created manually when I picked a new language in Project Info. It created me Main.strings(English) and Main.strings(Romanian). That's where I put my custom alerts messages.

Comment: @AhmadF ok, the localizable.strings were not set ok. going to answer now my question

Answer (score 2):

Rename your Localized.string file to Localizable.strings. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved it**

My issue was that I created those new strings into Main.strings file (The files that Xcode automatically creates for you when you select new languages in Project Info.

I had to create 2 new Strings file called "Localizable.strings" and Localize it one for english, one for romanian. I copied the strings I've written into `Main.strings` to `Localizable.strings` and now it works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

The name for the localizable file should be "Localizable.strings".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was in an incorrect format.
The problem did not arise immediately, but only after the next build cleanup (or tms like that). 
So, I found that lines from the end of the file are not translated, but from begin are.
And I turned out that one of the lines looked like

`= "some value";`

That is, there simply was no key. And the build was going without errors. But all the lines below were not translated.